# How to undo an action I did on the triage queue

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

I am not sure whether this has been asked or not. I couldn't find anything useful yet.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27405154

This post needs more clarity. I knew it, but accidentally clicked on <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd> button. Since the triage queue didn't ask for any confirmation and no undo method, I fear my triage queue will be suspended. What should I do now? Can any rectification be done in this case?

Comment: Vote/flag to close it if you don't think it should be open.

Comment: I flagged it as `Requires Editing` in the triage already and I can do it again ?

Comment: No, but as I said you can flag the post itself.

Comment: Okay I flagged the post? Now I have flagged twice with different flags. Which on would be they consider?

Comment: Requires editing is review feedback, not a flag. If you get suspended from review, you can mod flag one of your own posts and link to this meta post to show that you made a mistake and that you knew it was a mistake early (although dealing with the post appropriately outside review might be enough, given that the review bans are manual and mods can see flags). Aside that, accidents do happen - don't worry too much about it. You showing that it was a mistake early should be enough to avoid or at least get you out of it early

Comment: As for undoing, it wouldn't make sense to have an undo button since if people fail an Audit, they could undo their option to put the correct one in.